# GitLab pipeline script not resolving variables

Tags: bash, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci-runner

In one of the gitlab pipeline, we log into the docker hub. The following is a snippet of the `.gitlab-ci.yml`

build_image:
before_script:
docker login -u $LOGIN_USER -p $LOGIN_PASSWORD

`$LOGIN_USER` and `$LOGIN_PASSWORD` are gitlab variables set in Settings, they were supposed to be substite the value when docker login is run. For example, the above line would resolved to

```
docker login -u myuser -p 7GpfmQ,ukG>J:4K~;
```

The problem is that the password string had issues until I surround it with quotes, so more like

```
docker login -u myuser -p '7GpfmQ,ukG>J:4K~;'
```

If I hardcode this in the `.gitlab-ci.yml`, it works, but if I set `$LOGIN_PASSWORD` to `'7GpfmQ,ukG>J:4K~;'`, it does not work. I am curious to know why `docker login -u $LOGIN_USER -p $LOGIN_PASSWORD` is not working. When I do a echo `$LOGIN_PASSWORD`, it shows in the log that it has the correct value of `'7GpfmQ,ukG>J:4K~;'` and also hardcoding the value works.

Comment: Did you try to surround the variable with double quotes? Without adding the `'` in the password.

`docker login -u $LOGIN_USER -p "$LOGIN_PASSWORD"`

Comment: Please do what the [tag:bash] tag you used instructs and copy/paste your command into http://shellcheck.net then fix the issues it will tell you about.

Comment: When I use double quotes the extra symbols in the password causes the command to fail

Comment: I tried the following using shellcheck.net and it didn't say there were issues:  #!/bin/bash
LOGIN_USER="myuser"
LOGIN_PASSWORD="7GpfmQ,ukG>J:4K~"
docker login -u $LOGIN_USER -p $LOGIN_PASSWORD